# PIL-pillow's `Image.show()` removes temporary image before shown with okular

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I try to display a pil image using the `XDGViewer` viewer, okular (I am on kde, and okular is my default image viewer) displays a message it can't open the file. Indeed, it is not present in the /tmp when I look for it.

Since it works as expected with `DisplayViewer` (and the file is present until I close the window), I suspect xdg-open to launch okular and quit immediately, and then, since xdg closed, the file is removed immediately before okular can access it.

Is there a way to prevent deleting the temporary file (my /tmp is mounted on tmpfs, thus it's not really a problem...) ? for example, deleting the temporary file eigher when the image gets garbage-collected or when the interpreter closes ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are actually trying to do, nor what the problem is. What happens if you just do `xdg-open SOMEIMAGE.JPG` in your Terminal?

Comment: The problem is PIL removes the temporary image before okular has time to open it (xdg-open exit immediately, and use kf.services to launch it) thus, the image is gone...

Comment: You can register your own viewer which inherits from `PIL.ImageShow.Viewer` and is just a slightly adapted version of `class UnixViewer(Viewer)`

Comment: yes, that's what I ended up with... Do you know a way to make it the default when importing PIL ?

Comment: Not off-hand, but will have a think about it and report back if anything comes up. If you add the code you have so far it might inspire others to share their ideas...

Comment: Here it is : https://github.com/hl037/pillow-okular-viewer

Comment: Nice work. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: This sets the viewer as default on import, but yet it would be nice if a setting existed on PIL side to choose the default one, without even the need to manually import... but since `.show()` is a debugging feature, it is not that a problem I guess

Comment: This should be fixed in tomorrow's release of Pillow: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/5945#issuecomment-1045998524